# Injectivity and Surjectivity of a Function

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

We have the set $S$ that is the set of odd positive integers. A function $F:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow S$ is defined by $F(n)=k$ for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, where $k$ is an odd positive integer for which $3n+1=2^mk$ for some non-negative integer $m$. Prove or disprove the following:
(1) $F$ is injective. (2) $F$ is surjective.

I have thought of ways I could start to answer this question, but my attempts have been fruitless. Help would very much be appreciated for this question.

Million thanks in advance.

Comment: What does $B$ represent? Have you ever heard about the Collatz’s conjecture?

Comment: So sorry, there was a typo while typing the question. It should be S instead, and no, I have not heard of that conjecture before.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture

Comment: I suspect that you might not understand the definition of $F$. Can you try to give a few examples? What are the values of $F(2)$, $F(4)$, and $F(9)$?

Comment: @FlybyNight In all honesty, I cannot fathom what $F$ is.

Comment: @wsh_97 I've added an "answer" below. I hope it make sense. Please ask any more questions.

Answer (score 1):

What is $F$ doing? For any $n\in \mathbb N$ $F$ gives the odd factor of the prime decomposition of $3n+1$.

For injectivity note that $F(1)=F(21)=1$ (where $m=2$ and $m=6$ respectively).

For surjectivity consider what the implications are if $k=3$ in the equation $3n+1=k2^m$. Is $3n+1$ divisible by $3$ for any natural number $n$?

Comment: So I have followed your steps to consider the case when $k=3$. When we have an arbitrary non-negative $m$, we get a value that is always divisible by 3. On the other hand, when we take numbers for  $n=1$ to $n=10$, we see that this is not the case as $3n+1$ is not divisible by 3. Is it then sufficient to say that then $F$ is not surjective?

Comment: @wsh_97 The point is that $3n+1$ is never divisible by $3$, because $3n$ is divisible by $3$ for all $n$. This means that $\frac{3n+1}{3}$ is never an integer. Hence there is no $m$ or $n$ such that $\frac{3n+1}{3}=2^m$. Thus $F(n)\neq 3$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1):

For any integer $n$, calculate $3n+1$. Once you have $3n+1$ write that as a product by taking out as many factors of $2$ as possible. The remaining odd factor is the value of $F(n)$.

If $n=1$, then $3n+1 = 4$, and $4=2^2 \times 1$, so $m=2$ and $k=1$. Hence $F(1)=1$

If $n=2$, then $3n+1 = 7$, and $7 = 2^0 \times 7$, so $m=0$ and $k=7$. Hence $F(2)=7$

If $n=3$, then $3n+1 = 10$, and $10 = 2^1 \times 5$, so $m=1$ and $k=5$. Hence $F(3)=5$

If $n=4$, then $3n+1 = 13$, and $13 = 2^0 \times 13$, so $m=0$ and $k=13$. Hence $F(4) = 13$

If $n=5$, then $3n+1 = 16$, and $16 = 2^4 \times 1$, so $m=4$ and $k=1$. Hence $F(5) = 1$